# Uploading Excel table into a Wordpress phpmyadmin database

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, import-from-excel

Is it possible to upload a user frontend uploaded table and send it to phpmyadmin database and then display it on the website? I've tried searching everywhere but there simply isn't anything I've found on that matter.

All Wordpress plugins I checked out are for me to upload them instead of the users on the frontend.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding exactly what your asking for here. Could you elaborate? What do you mean by "upload a user frontend uploaded table"?

Comment: I'd like for a logged in user to upload his own complete table into my database so i could show it on my website, or he doesnt even have to upload it to a database just make it showable on the frontend with standard HTML table tags. Hope you understand what i mean as english isnt really my first language ;/

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. You're trying to allow users to insert a whole database table into your database. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes sir. And then for it to be showable on my website where if i inspect element i'll be able to see the table structure

Comment: Build a file upload form on your site and allow CSV files. In the PHP code that will handle the uploaded file, you write the proper code to import CSVs into your database. This can be risky, consider security while processing the file. The user will have to know to make a CSV from excel.

Comment: Right, thank you very much. Dunno if i can mark this as correct or something as its only a comment but if there's a way to give you credit or something feel free to let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a file upload form on your site and allow CSV files. In the PHP code that will handle the uploaded file, you write the proper code to import CSVs into your database. This can be risky, consider security while processing the file. The user will have to know to make a CSV from excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the Excel table as csv file. You have to choose the csv file where they use semicolons as separator. If you trust the Google Translator it's called "CSV (separator separated)". It will sperarate the columns with semicolons.

Then you go to phpmyadmin, select your table and click on import.
Select your file, and select "CSV" under "Format".

Then you press "OK" and your csv file should be converted to a table in your database.

Comment: Thank you, but thats if i want to upload them, while i need other people to upload their tables thru the frontend of my website and convert them to a table in my database